# Is there a sample code in the yaml-cpp new API which involves "while(parser.GetNextDocument(doc)) {..}"

Tags: yaml-cpp

In yaml-cpp, how do you change the old API snippet:

```
YAML::Node doc;
while(parser.GetNextDocument(doc)) {
       // ...
}
```

into the new API?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
std::vector<YAML::Node> docs = YAML::LoadAll("--- foo\n--- bar\n");
```

(or the analogous `LoadAllFromFile`) to parse a sequence of documents.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and correcting my low quality English (Am a Japanese).